# How i make this tabs on extensions messages

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

i try to make an bot with similar layout

[image]

we can see it on microsoft teams doc [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/what-are-messaging-extensions)

I use this search example and get an result, but i dont know to make this "tabs" (Recents, Reports, inside image), anyone know or have example to how i make it?

i have only search input and result list, but i need tabs.

Thanks for all

Comment: The pic that you posted is of messaging extension, but your question seems unclear to me. Can you please elaborate your use case in detail as to why you want bots with this layout. Thanks.

Comment: @Manish-MSFTthanks for comment, i need know how to make tabs (idk if have this name) inside a message extension, on picture, we can see two tabs, Recents and Reports, when you click in any, show other options on the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are actually called messaging extension search commands. Please try providing multiple commands by providing id's, title and other fields to render them as tabs.[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/search-commands/define-search-command#manually-create-a-command) documentation serves as best reference guide.

Answer (score 0):

As tabs are only supported by search commands of message extension. To add tabs in your message extension, you would have to define the search commands in the manifest.json file of your respective project with id, title, and other required details.

```
"commands": [
    {
      "id": "searchQuery",
      "context": [ "compose", "commandBox" ],
      "description": "Test command to run query",
      "title": "Search",
      "type": "query",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "searchQuery",
          "title": "Search Query",
          "description": "Your search query",
          "inputType": "text"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```